# Ubuntu shutting down Java before OutOfMemory exception is thrown

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to solve an ILP with the IBM CPLEX Java/OPL library. The solve method runs in an if-loop which returns false if there were problems with the ILP (such as not enough memory or infeasible solution).

```
    try {
        Log.printLine("Starting CPLEX solve");
        if (cplex.solve()) {
            Log.printLine("CPLEX solved successfully, now processing result");
        } else {
            Log.printLine("Solution could not be achieved, probably insufficient memory or some other weird problem.");
        }
    } catch (IloException e) {
        Log.printLine("Solution could not be achieved, probably insufficient memory or some other weird problem.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Log.printLine("just making sure we can reach this!");
    }
```

The problem is that when I run `java -Xmx24g -jar myjar.jar &` on my machine with 44GB RAM, the Ubuntu kernel keeps shutting down my ILP while it is in the cplex.solve() method. My syslog files say `Killed proces Java -Xmx24g -jar myjar.jar &`. For some reason my RAM usage goes up to +44GB making me think that this ILP is not taking heap space (then what is causing this huge memory usage?).

Furthermore the Ubuntu kernel is shutting down my java process before it can finish solving or before an OutOfMemory exception is thrown.

I'd really like my ILP to finish naturally so I can keep the program running, does anyone know how I can configure Ubuntu or my java arguments to avoid this current Ubuntu behavior?

Comment: Very speculative: maybe some endless-loop detection? Needing a `volatile` to communicate between threads or such?

Comment: Well the problem is that it's a direct library call from an IBM library. Im afraid I dont know what happens inside it and I also dont really have any hooks to plug in to.